# Beginning at the end of 'a', insert 'b' after every 3rd character of 'a'

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to solve this challenge (found at jschallenger.com):

1. Write a function that takes two strings (a and b) as arguments
2. Beginning at the end of 'a', insert 'b' after every 3rd character of
   'a'
3. Return the resulting string

This is my solution so far (Which I was sure would work):

```js
function insertEveryThree(a, b) {
  let arr = a.split('')

  for (let i = arr.length - 3; i > 0; i -= 3) {

    arr.splice(i, 0, b)

  }
  return arr.join('')
}

console.log(insertEveryThree('actionable', '-')) // a-cti-ona-ble
console.log(insertEveryThree('1234567', '.')) // 1.234.567
console.log(insertEveryThree('abcde', '$')) // ab$cde
console.log(insertEveryThree('zxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz', 'w')) // zwxyzwxyzwxyzwxyzwxyz
```

Where am I failing at?

Comment: because `arr.length` is changing each time you insert something in that loop

Comment: what exactly seems to be the problem? what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the string with a regular expression.

```js
function insertEveryThree(a, b) {
    return a.replace(/(?=(...)+$)/g, b);
}

console.log(insertEveryThree('actionable', '-')) // a-cti-ona-ble
console.log(insertEveryThree('1234567', '.')) // 1.234.567
console.log(insertEveryThree('abcde', '$')) // ab$cde
console.log(insertEveryThree('zxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz', 'w')) // zwxyzwxyzwxyzwxyzwxyz
```

Comment: I was in favor of a regex solution too, but I couldn't figure out exactly what the problem was.  It looks like what the question described, but it's the same output as what the OP had.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push into a new array, splicing mutates the array and causes problems with indexes:

```
function insertEveryThree(str, character, index = 3) {
  const strArr = str.split("");
  const newArr = [];

  for (const i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(strArr[i]);

    if ((i + 1) % index === 0 && i !== 0 && i + 1 < str.length) {
      newArr.push(character);
    }
  }

  return newArr.join("");
}
console.log(insertEveryThree("actionable", "-")); // act-ion-abl-e
console.log(insertEveryThree("1234567", ".")); // 123.456.7
console.log(insertEveryThree("abcde", "$")); // abc$de
console.log(insertEveryThree("zxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz", "w")); // zxywzxywzxywzxywzxywz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
   let result = [];
   let rest = a;
   while (rest.length) {
    result.push(rest.slice(-3));
    rest = rest.slice(0, -3);
   }
   return result.reverse().join(b);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why it works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.